# How to refresh a listview inside a collapsed div

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, refresh

I'm using jQuery Mobile listview inside a collapsible div.
The listview has data-inset=true
The .listview('refresh') method doesn't work if the div is collapsed.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/giofiddle/muDqS/) for an example.

JavaScript:

```
var count = 1;

$('.add').click(function() {
    $('#1, #2').append('<li>' + count + '</li>');
    $("ul").listview('refresh');
    count++;
});
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <a class="add" href="#">Add Item</a>
        <ul id="1" data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
            <li data-role="list-divider">List 1</li>
        </ul>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Collapsible</h3>
            <ul id="2" data-inset="true" data-role="listview">
                <li data-role="list-divider">List 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading answers to other questions I discovered it is possible to call the method `listview('refresh')` with an extra parameter:

```
listview('refresh',true)
```

I didn't find documentation about this possibility, so I can't explain why this solve the problem.

You can test the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/giofiddle/bxHjS/

Bye